# Unusual problem when dragging a child control in C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, mousemove

I found some code here and elsewhere on the net about how to drag child controls inside of a form with the mouse at runtime.  The goal is to let the user arrange these and other child controls on the form.  Right now my main form has two controls, pictureBox1 and panel1.  pictureBox1 has a photo in it, and panel1 has a button and some text boxes.  Each of these controls can be moved when the user left-clicks inside either one of them and drags it, so I handle mouse down, mouse move and mouse up events. The code is working with just these two child controls, but I'm not sure why.  Below are my mouse down and mouse move event handlers:

```
    private Point MouseDownLocation;
    private Point controlDestinationLocation;
    private void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // label1 shows e.X and e.Y whenever the mouse is over panel1 or pictureBox1
        label1.Text = "Mouseover (e.X,e.Y): (" + e.X + "," + e.Y + ")";
        // If the left mouse button is down, set MouseDownLocation to the current mouse coordinates
        // and controlDestinationLocation to the upper left corner of either panel1 or pictureBox1
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            Control ctrl = (Control)sender;
            ctrl.BringToFront();
            controlDestinationLocation = ctrl.Location;
            // ...and display the locations
            label2.Text = "MouseDown: (" + MouseDownLocation.X + "," + MouseDownLocation.Y + ")";
            label3.Text = "Destination: (" + controlDestinationLocation.X + "," + controlDestinationLocation.Y + ")";
            label4.Text = "Left button pressed (e.X,e.Y): (" + e.X + "," + e.Y + ")";
        }
    }

    private void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // label1 shows e.X and e.Y whenever the mouse is over panel1 or pictureBox1
        label1.Text = "Mouseover (e.X,e.Y): (" + e.X + "," + e.Y + ")";
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            // If the left mouse button is down, move the child control first
            Control thisCtrl = (Control)sender;
            int dX = e.X - MouseDownLocation.X;
            int dY = e.Y - MouseDownLocation.Y;
            thisCtrl.Left += dX;
            thisCtrl.Top += dY;
            // Then display all the locations in text boxes
            label2.Text = "MouseDown: (" + MouseDownLocation.X + "," + MouseDownLocation.Y + ")";
            label3.Text = "Destination: (" + controlDestinationLocation.X + "," + controlDestinationLocation.Y + ")";
            label4.Text = "Left button pressed (e.X,e.Y): (" + e.X + "," + e.Y + ")";
            label5.Text = "(dX,dY): (" + dX + "," + dY + ")";
            int X1 = pictureBox1.Location.X;
            int Y1 = pictureBox1.Location.Y;
            int X2 = pictureBox1.Right;
            int Y2 = pictureBox1.Bottom;
            label6.Text = "pictureBox1: (" + X1 + "," + Y1 + ") - (" + X2 + ", " + Y2 + ")";
            X1 = panel1.Location.X;
            Y1 = panel1.Location.Y;
            X2 = panel1.Right;
            Y2 = panel1.Bottom;
            label7.Text = "panel1: (" + X1 + "," + Y1 + ") - (" + X2 + ", " + Y2 + ")";
        }
    }
```

In control_MouseMove(), thisCtrl.Left and thisCtrl.Top (the upper left corner of the child control), are updated correctly by the variables dX and dY, but what I don't understand is this: When I display dX and dY (using a text box inside panel1), they both turn out to be zero, but at the same time thisCtrl.Left and thisCtrl.Top are both updated by some nonzero values because the child control I drag is moving.  So, either dX is one value when updating thisCtrl.Left than it is when displayed in a text box (same goes for dY), or I am missing something.  Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: *When I display dX and dY (using a text box inside panel1)*: when does this happen? If you mean what's been written to `label5.Text`, `dX` and `dY` represent a difference that changes for each mouse movement, so they're going to be `0`, `-1`, `1` (mostly) -- *The code is working with just these two child controls, but I'm not sure why*: are other Controls subscribing to those events using the same handlers? -- `controlDestinationLocation` is actually the original location.

Comment: Jimi, thanks for your response.  Yes, the two controls are both subscribing to the same mouse event handlers.  And you are correct, dX and dY are being displayed in label5.Text.  I put several text boxes inside of panel1 called label1 through label7, and these are in numerical order from top to bottom, so  label1 displays e.X and e.Y whenever the mouse moves inside of either child control, label2 shows the MouseDown location, label3 shows controlDestinationLocation, etc.

Comment: What I am having trouble understanding is, when I left-click in the upper left-hand corner of pictureBox1, label4 shows, for example, that e.X and e.Y are (2,2), and at the same time MouseDownLocation is set to (2,2).  Then, while I am dragging pictureBox1, (e.X,e.Y) and MouseDownLocation stay at (2,2).  That means (e.X,e.Y) displayed in label4 are in 'child control' coordinates, meaning from the upper left-hand corner (0,0) of pictureBox1.  But if (e.X,e.Y) and MouseDownLocation are always (2,2), then how does pictureBox1.Location ever change, since zero is (apparently) being added to it?

Comment: It moves because of this:  `thisCtrl.Left += dX; thisCtrl.Top += dY;`. Note that you're adding to the `Left` and `Top` positions of the Control. `e.X` and `e.Y` reference the position of the Mouse pointer inside the Control's ClientArea. Since you're dragging the Control moving the mouse, each pixel of movement raises the event, so you're adding values in the range `(-1; 1)`. When the Control is moved, the Mouse Pointer's position inside the ClientArea is also moved, which resets `e.X - MouseDownLocation.X;` and `Y` to `0` right after. Printing to a Label, you'll *see `0`* most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Jimi, I think you are exactly right that seeing 0 most of the time is the answer.

I assumed if I didn't move the mouse then I'd see `dX` and/or `dY` as nonzero at least sometimes, but I think the label controls I'm using get updated so often that I am only seeing 0.

Instead of using text labels to watch the mouse move, I copied `e.X` and `e.Y` to an array of `Point` values while the mouse was moving and saw nonzero values.

Thanks.